# Building POCO libraries with CMake in Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking, poco-libraries, nmake

I am currently building POCO libraries with CMake like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "NMake Makefiles" -DPOCO_STATIC .
nmake
```

It all works fine, except for the fact that libraries aren't created with suffix `mtd.lib` or `mdd.lib`, just `d.lib`. Because of this, then my application fails to link to `PocoFoundationsmdd.lib` since the file doesn't exist.

Is there any keyword to pass in the `cmake` command so that it builds with the right prefix? I know that from Visual Studio there are configurations like `debug_static_md` one can select, but is it possible to do it through `cmake` without modifying the `CMakelists.txt`?

Comment: Why have you decided that the libraries should have such a suffix? If I remember correctly a `<something>d.<platform-specific-extensions>` is what you get in case of POCO debug build. Of course you could edit `CMakeLists.txt` but for what?

Comment: When compiling with MSVC the POCO libraries have #pragma comment(lib, ...) that automatically link to the proper type of libraries. See http://pocoproject.org/docs/99150-WindowsPlatformNotes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was as simple as adding `add_definitions( -DPOCO_STATIC -DPOCO_NO_AUTOMATIC_LIBS)` to the CMakelists.txt that is consuming the POCO libraries compiled with cmake. That effectively disables the header (`*.h`) definitions that attempt to link from the code:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #if !defined(POCO_NO_AUTOMATIC_LIBS) && !defined(Crypto_EXPORTS)
        #pragma comment(lib, "PocoXXX" POCO_LIB_SUFFIX)
    #endif
#endif
```